# IP/Packets Forwarding

Tags: networking, vpn, ip-forwarding

I have searched a lot about IP + Packets forwarding but there was not enough information to find.
Is forwarding only used in case of Virtual Private Networking or it has also other uses? if yes, when are they used? and what is the purpose of them anyway?

Comment: It's used to build a thing called the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forwarding an IP packet occurs whenever a device (which is not the intended recipient) receives an IP packet, and the device understands how to send the IP packet to the intended recipient. This happens constantly on the Internet. Your PC wants to connect to Google, but your computer is not directly connect to a Google Server, so the packet has to be fowarded to your router, your ISP, Google's ISP, and into Google's network.